# Fragment ListView ContextMenu with AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-dialogfragment, android-contextmenu

I have a `ListView` that is within a `Fragment`. The `ListView` has a `ContextMenu` to edit and delete entries. I am trying to set a `DialogFragment` to launch on selection of the `EDIT` option of my `ContextMenu`, however nothing is being displayed when edit is chosen. Is this a view problem? Thanks in advance.

Original Post:

```
public static class FragmentS extends Fragment {

    private ListView saveListView;
    private List<LiftSave> LiftSaves = new ArrayList<LiftSave>();
    private static final int EDIT = 0, DELETE = 1;

    LiftSave longClickedItemLiftSave;
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
    ArrayAdapter<LiftSave> saveAdapter;


    public FragmentS() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_s,
                container, false);
        saveListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.saveListView);
        registerForContextMenu(saveListView);
        DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler (getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        if (dbHandler.getLiftSavesCount() != 0)
            LiftSaves.addAll(dbHandler.getAllLiftSaves());

        populateList();

        saveListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                longClickedItemLiftSave = (LiftSave) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private void populateList() {
        saveAdapter = new SaveListAdapter();
        saveListView.setAdapter(saveAdapter);
    }


    public class SaveListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LiftSave> {
            public SaveListAdapter() {
                super(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item, LiftSaves);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (view == null)
                    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

                LiftSave currentLiftSave = LiftSaves.get(position);

                TextView liftName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.liftName);
                liftName.setText(currentLiftSave.getLiftName());
                TextView maxValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.maxValue);
                maxValue.setText(currentLiftSave.getMaxValue());
                TextView weightAndReps = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.weightAndReps);
                weightAndReps.setText(currentLiftSave.getRepsAndWeight());
                TextView liftNotes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.liftNotes);
                liftNotes.setText(currentLiftSave.getLiftNotes());
                TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.todayDate);
                date.setText(currentLiftSave.getTodayDate());

                return view;
            }

    }
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);

        menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.pencil_icon);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Save Options");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, EDIT, menu.NONE, "Edit Save");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE, menu.NONE, "Delete Save");
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case EDIT:
                // TODO: Add save edit code
                break;
            case DELETE:
             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                                dbHandler.deleteLiftSave(longClickedItemLiftSave);
                                saveAdapter.remove(longClickedItemLiftSave);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                break;
                            }
                            return super.
                            onContextItemSelected(item);
                        }
        }
```

Updated from Suggestions:

```
    public static class FragmentS extends Fragment {

    private ListView saveListView;
    private List<LiftSave> LiftSaves = new ArrayList<LiftSave>();
    private static final int EDIT = 0, DELETE = 1;

    LiftSave longClickedItemLiftSave;
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
    ArrayAdapter<LiftSave> saveAdapter;


    public FragmentS() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_s,
                container, false);
        saveListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.saveListView);
        registerForContextMenu(saveListView);
        DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler (getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        if (dbHandler.getLiftSavesCount() != 0)
            LiftSaves.addAll(dbHandler.getAllLiftSaves());

        populateList();

        saveListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                longClickedItemLiftSave = (LiftSave) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private void populateList() {
        saveAdapter = new SaveListAdapter();
        saveListView.setAdapter(saveAdapter);
    }


    public class SaveListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LiftSave> {
            public SaveListAdapter() {
                super(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item, LiftSaves);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (view == null)
                    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

                LiftSave currentLiftSave = LiftSaves.get(position);

                TextView liftName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.liftName);
                liftName.setText(currentLiftSave.getLiftName());
                TextView maxValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.maxValue);
                maxValue.setText(currentLiftSave.getMaxValue());
                TextView weightAndReps = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.weightAndReps);
                weightAndReps.setText(currentLiftSave.getRepsAndWeight());
                TextView liftNotes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.liftNotes);
                liftNotes.setText(currentLiftSave.getLiftNotes());
                TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.todayDate);
                date.setText(currentLiftSave.getTodayDate());

                return view;
            }

    }
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);

        menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.pencil_icon);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Save Options");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, EDIT, menu.NONE, "Edit Save");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE, menu.NONE, "Delete Save");
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case EDIT:
                // TODO: Add save edit code

                Context thisContext = getActivity().getBaseContext();
                View dialogViewEdit = LayoutInflater.from(thisContext).inflate(R.layout.edit_save, null, false);
                final EditText editName = (EditText) dialogViewEdit.findViewById(R.id.editLiftName);
                AlertDialog.Builder builderE = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
                AlertDialog dialog = builderE.create();
                builderE.setView(dialogViewEdit);
                dialog.show();
                break;
            case DELETE: //WORKING!
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this save?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                                dbHandler.deleteLiftSave(longClickedItemLiftSave);
                                saveAdapter.remove(longClickedItemLiftSave);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog dialogD = builder.create();
                dialogD.show();


                break;
                            }
                            return super.
                            onContextItemSelected(item);
                        }
        }
```

The `EDIT` option reflects a custom view from an `XML Layout`. On selection it shows `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`. Pointing to the line `dialog.show();`. Such was resolved by calling `Context thisContext = getActivity().getBaseContext();` as the the `Context` for the `LayoutInflater`. However while no error takes place, the screen simply darkens as though a `Dialog` was launched, but nothing appears. The `DELETE` option when selected correctly launches and functions by calling `new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());`. Yet, `this.getActivity()` yields the same result when used in place of `thisContext` for the `EDIT` option. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext())

Comment: seems you forgot to do AlertDialog alertdialog = builder.create(); alertDialog.show();

Comment: @pkBhati thanks for the input. That works, however I get `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application` on `  dialog.show();`.

Comment: @androidpotato7 I've since added `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();dialog.show();`.                                               As I mentioned to @pkBhati it ends up a `BadTokenException`

Comment: @Austin, It seems you made some updates, pls post your updated code.

Comment: @Austin, What's wrong with the (Alert) Dialog? Is it doing the requested deletion or whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to display the dialog after the builder setup, like:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
...

.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
   }
 });

 // Create the AlertDialog
 AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
 dialog.show();
```

It is also a good idea to set and control your own views, like:

```
Context thisContext = this.getActivity().getBaseContext();

View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(thisContext).inflate(R.layout.dialog_edit_1, null, false);
final EditText editName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editName);

builder.setView(dialogView);
```

If you have a problem with getting the correct context, and it seems you do. Code sample:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
   thisContext = view.getContext();
}
```

Notes:

- Since the DELETE option is in a nested class, using `this` object in this.getActivity() seems necessary, oddly.
- The code `AlertDialog dialog = builder.create()` should be placed after buttons setting, like in sample code.
- I do `setView`() before `setPositiveButton` call.
- editName is the variable to get a user selected name, as an example.
- Try `dialog.show()` first since that is required.
- There's a good Google webpage @ [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), search for "Adding buttons".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What would the `Context` be `.from(thisContext)` in this case? I created something similar with a new layout, but I don't think I can call `this`? Its showed as an error.

Comment: Try getActivity().getBaseContext() or getActivity().getApplicationContext() in your method. I updated my post. Normally I get the context from the override onViewCreated method, and then I save it for future use. If so, the code will be view.getContext().

Comment: AlertDialog dialogD = builder.create();
dialogD.show();
The code above should be placed after setting the buttons. I'll update my post.

Comment: The 4th bullet suggests to read up on the webpage. Pls do so, it's helpful for your problem.

Comment: If you have a problem with getting the correct context, please read up my post on it.

Comment: Again I've updated my post. The custom `Dialog` issue persists. I was able to resolve the `DELETE` option by simply calling `this.getActivity()`. You've been a great help, if you add that to your answer I'd like to mark it for others, as well as any further input you might have with my update. Thanks again.

Comment: I am glad for you. I updated my answer to mention using "this" object in few places. I am going to test/investigate this object further. It's as if the nested class is confused about which object should be used in context of  getActivity().

Comment: `case EDIT:
// TODO: Add save edit code
View dialogViewEdit = LayoutInflater.from(this.getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.edit_save, null, false);
AlertDialog.Builder builderE = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
builderE.create();
builderE.setView(dialogViewEdit);                                                 builderE.show();
break;`                                                                                                               Is the full solution. `Context` Appears not be necessary, who knows?